# Абсолютное позиционирование окна предупреждения

Tags: jquery, css

***Добрый день***

Подскажите пожалуйста, необходимо сделать следующее:
Позиционирование элемента с `position: absolute;`, который вложен в элемент с `position: relative;`, четко по центру.

Вот то, что я **[сделал](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/qJrym/7/).**

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="error-box">
    <input type="text" />
    <p class="error-message">Введите данные</p>
    </div>
```

</div>

css:

```
.error-box {
    position: relative;
}
.error-message {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #909090;
    color: #fff;
    font: bold 16px Arial;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

jquery:

```
var em = $('.error-message'); // em - error-message
var emo = em.prev(); // emo - error-message-object
var offset = $('.error-box').offset();
var left = offset.left + emo.width()/2 - em.width()/2;
em.css({
    'left' : left,
    'top' : offset.top + emo.height() + 15
});
```

Таких блоков на странице может быть несколько, и элемент с `class="error-message"` может находиться не только под текстовым полем, но и под любым другим элементом, например под таким: `<input type="submit" value="Отправить данные" />`

Необходимо к элементу с `class="error-message"` добавить стрелку, чтобы она находилась сверху данного элемента, указывая на `error-message-object` и была четко по центру.

Comment: @Deonis, сильно не "пинайте". Ваше замечание из последнего комментария я учел. Что касается именно этого вопроса, то планы несколько изменились, теперь блок сообщения должен находиться на странице. Пытался применить Ваше решение, но не получилось.

Comment: @Deonis, вот еще более свежее обновление: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/7vh6q/

Comment: Предлагаю, @Alex83 немного собраться с мыслями, и таки выразить в тексте то, что он хочет получить. а то я присоединяюсь к товарищу @Deonis :)

Comment: @istem, необходимо получить блок предупреждения, который бы располагался, снизу, четко по центру элемента, идущего перед ним.
Вот фотография макета: http://крепежстрой.рф/form/image.jpg


Вот что было сделано: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/7vh6q/

Блок предупреждения резиновый, абсолютно позиционированный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, [посмотри тут](http://jsfiddle.net/RtGpn/). Постарался оставить твою структуру html, но если честно, очень хотелось поправить. :)

Comment: @istem, спасибо огромное. А что именно хотелось поправить и почему?

Comment: Собственно, можно оставить только 
     <input type="text" />
        <p class="error-message">
            <span class="triangle"></span>
            <span class="mess_txt">Введите данные</span>
        </p> лишние обёртки ни к чему. (хотя тут нужно смотреть общую картину)

Answer (score 0):

[[@Alex83](/users/8823/alex83)](/users/8823/alex83), толи сказывается моя бессонная ночь, толи я действительно не могу понять, что значит фраза:

> планы несколько изменились, теперь
> блок сообщения должен находиться на
> странице

До этого он находилась у соседа в квартире? )))
В общем, если по поводу стрелки, то можно сделать с помощью CSS [вот таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/qJrym/8/)

Comment: @Deonis, я имел ввиду, что данный элемент не будет добавляться на страницу с помощью jquery, а будет прописан в html. Со стрелкой понятно, а по поводу позиционирования не поможете?

Comment: @Alex83, точный кусок HTML-кода покажите, а то какие-то несостыковочки в том, что вы показали здесь и на jsFiddle.

Comment: @Deonis, на jsFiddle правильный вариант.

Comment: @Alex83, правильный? У вас тоже ночь без сна? )) Внимательно посмотрите, удивитесь тому, что у вас один не закрытый div внутри другого, исправьте и обновите ссылку.